# inputs in component aren't updating correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have component that is going to be used many times. It's basically to inputs that will represent two width and height dimensions.

Couple of things going on with them right now. When I start typing in them, when they are both empty, the last character is not recorded. if I type:

> 1234 x 1234

when I refresh the inputs show:

> 1234 x 123

then if I edit one of the inputs, the other will just go blank.

Here's my code:

```
import React from 'react';

// Shared Components
import { FlexRow } from 'components/shared/Flexbox';
import { TextInput } from 'components/shared/TextInput';

export class RenderDimensionsInput extends React.Component {
  state = {
    readOnly: '',
    width: null,
    height: null
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    console.log('e.target.name', e.target.name);
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

    console.log('this.state.height', this.state.height);
    console.log('this.state.width', this.state.width);

    this.props.onChange(this.state.height, this.state.width);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <FlexRow>
          <TextInput
            label={this.props.label}
            style={{ width: '135px', marginRight: '10px' }}
            defaultValue={this.props.values.width}
            name="width"
            // onChange={this.props.onChange}
            onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}
          />
          <span>x</span>
          <TextInput
            style={{ width: '135px', marginLeft: '10px' }}
            defaultValue={this.props.values.height}
            name="height"
            // onChange={this.props.onChange}
            onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}
          />
        </FlexRow>
      </div>
    );
  }
}




export class TextInput extends React.Component {
  state = {
    readOnly: '',
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <FlexColumn
        style={{
          alignItems: 'baseline',
          paddingBottom: s[3],
        }}>
        <Input
          {...this.props}
          type={this.props.type || 'text'}
          defaultValue={this.props.defaultValue}
          onChange={this.props.onChange}
          readOnly={this.state.readOnly}
        />
        <Label>{this.props.label}</Label>
      </FlexColumn>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the value from `state` directly after setting the state, but setState is `async` which means that there is no guarantee that at that moment you are using the latest `state` in:  `this.props.onChange(this.state.height, this.state.width);`

So it is better to use it that way:

```
this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value }, () => {
  this.props.onChange(this.state.height, this.state.width);
});
```

Comment: excellent! thank you. So that fixes the problem of my last character not being recorded. I still have the problem that if both inputs have a value, and I edit one of them, the other get's cleared.

Comment: Does TextInput has a value prop ?

Comment: Yes, it does. I'll add it to the question

Comment: why are you using `defaultValue` and not `value` ?

Comment: Not completely sure, I inherited this app. But I'm kinda locked into using it I think.

Comment: So, the other input is getting cleared because this.state.n is null. I am trying to put some logic in to determine which input is being edited, but it's not working and I certain there is a better way:

Comment: this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value }, e => {
      if (e.target.name === 'height') {
        this.props.onChange(this.state.height);
      } else {
        this.props.onChange(this.state.width);
      }
    });